# How to get Single XElement object using Linq to Xml?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I would like to use Linq to Xml to get a single XElement from a .xml file by attribute name, similar to how you retrieve single objects in Linq to Sql by Id below:

```
var singleDog = context.Dogs.Single(p => p.Id == int.Parse(Id));
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Good question, Kevin. I'm trying to get my head around linq to xml and this question (and the answer) were helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely. Just use something like:

```
xdoc.Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.HasAttribute("id") && x.Attribute("id")==id)
    .Single();
```

There may be a more efficient way of doing it, admittedly...

Comment: this statement does have one issue, I found, and it is that the XElement object doesn't have a HasAttribute property.  If I remove that from the Lambda expression it works great!.

Comment: I also made the following statement work as well!

xmlDoc.Descendants("Site").Single(p => (string)p.Attribute("Name") == rootName);

where rootName is a string type.

Comment: What does that do for elements which don't have a Name attribute though?

Comment: I would have used SingleOrDefault to avoid the null ref exception and then make a null check afterwards.